# How to navigate to another stack in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate from "Auth" stack to "App" stack.
I got response exactly from backend,(Laravel) but it doesn't navigate to "App" stack.
That is my code.

How to navigate from "SignIn" screen to "Home" screen?

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    First: FirstScreen,
    SignIn: SignInScreen,                     //-----> Navigate from here
    SignUp: SignUpScreen,
    ForgotPass: ForgotPassScreen,
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'First'
});


const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

const HistoryStack = createStackNavigator({
    History: { screen: HistoryScreen },
});

const RepaymentStack = createStackNavigator({
    Repayment: { screen: RepaymentScreen },
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});


const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: HomeStack },            //-----> Navigate to here
        History: { screen: HistoryStack },
        Repayment: { screen: RepaymentStack },
        Profile: { screen: ProfileStack },
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
            Auth: AuthStack,
            App: AppStack,
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SignIn screen is a class, you should use navigation.navigate

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
```

The switch navigator will navigate to the App stack and as Home is the first tab it would be shown.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. but failed again. SignIn screen is a class, Is there any another way ?

Comment: you can check out this snack https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/switch-navigator

Comment: If "SignIn" is not initialRouteName in AuthStack, is it possible to navigate from SignIn to App stack? And "AppStack" is not createStackNavigator, but a createBottomTabNavigator. In this case?

Comment: Wont make a difference for some reason i cant install the bottom tab nav in snack but for switch navigator it just another route so it should work